# Div and Image Margin/Padding

Tags: css, xhtml

Can anyone tell me why the below CSS produces extra margin below the image? It should just add a 5px padding around the whole thing and it works fine with text. Any ideas?

```
div#somediv {
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
}

div#somediv img {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

<div id="somediv">
  <img src="someimage.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: There wasn't any additional margin below image as how I have rendered it in FF3.5.7. Neither will the code be producing any margin except the 5px padding from the div#somediv.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try making the image a block-level element:

```
div#somediv img
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```